# stars and slideshow input not working in IE browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

http://abc.com/abc.php?alias=Rashtreeya-Vidyalaya-College-of-Engineering-Mysore-Road-Bangalore&product=colleges

I have a page like this .this works very well in all browsers, but not in IE.

problem in IE is that :
1. If  you go to "your ratings" tab  in second section. the stars and input are not clickable only.
2. and the gap between tabs and tables are more in IE ..

tried to check in firebug also. the element has not margin or padding at bottom.

3. the slideshow also does not work in IE

Comment: More information would be great. What version of IE? What's some of the associated CSS code with it?

Comment: It seems to work in IE8, but the code of the page is horrible. Clean up typing errors and standards non-compliance, then you can start bugtracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...
Former internet explorer versions had a mistake in their box model:
the w3c box model takes width without padding and border, and the IE model took it including them.
I have examined the page in a a new IE8 in windows 7, and I've only noticed that the border of the tabs were not rounded and they were not connected to the box. The corner can be done with images.

Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create a different page design by detecting the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(navigator.appCodeName);
</script>
```

As you can see, at CNET.com it is different when you switch browsers.
Firefox and Chrome are both very similar, Internet Explorer is extremely simple.

Comment: No.  At the worst, he should only have to append IE "fix" styles using conditional comments.

Comment: Internet Explorer just sucks.
I can't believe someone would vote that down.

Comment: @Brock Adams  - do you find anything fishy in code . or any IE fix you suggest for my problem.

Comment: @pradeep: No, it even validates with only warnings.  I didn't activate javascript or test it in IE.  I couldn't see anything obviously wrong, using Firebug, and I've no patience to investigate any more IE bugs today.  Sorry.  :(

Comment: @Brock Adams - thanks . yeah i had validated it before posting it over here. if you find this interesting and some time . just find the bug . ;)

Comment: -1 for suggesting that horrible practice, if a version working in all browsers can't be made, then conditional comments is by far the preferred way of fixing for IE.